# add textfield to tableviewheader

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I am trying to add textfield to header view. I could not figure out why I can't see my textfield. When I use a label it works perfectly.

Following is the code:

```
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 70, 30)];
    UITextField *sectionTitleTF1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 0, 500, 30)];
    sectionTitleTF1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [sectionTitleTF1 becomeFirstResponder];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview:sectionTitleTF1];
return tableHeaderView;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Very likely that your rects for sectionTitleTF1 and/or tableHeaderView are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
  You can adjust view, textfield frame based on your device ipad or iphone




 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 30.0;
}

-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 70, 30)];
tableHeaderView.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];
UITextField *sectionTitleTF1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 0, 500, 30)];
sectionTitleTF1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[sectionTitleTF1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[sectionTitleTF1 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
[sectionTitleTF1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[sectionTitleTF1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[sectionTitleTF1 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
[sectionTitleTF1 becomeFirstResponder];
[tableHeaderView addSubview:sectionTitleTF1];
return tableHeaderView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented this method of the datasource? It is a must if you want your section header to show.
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30.0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Also, if you are unaware, you can return the `UITextField` directly rather than adding as a subview. However you may want it as a subview, depending on what you want to achieve.

EDIT: Datasource not Delegate

Comment: Yes I did add delegate. It works when I add textfield to cell in the same class but not for section header.

Comment: Not just setting the datasource but you must implement the methods as above in the (edited) answer. You must set the height of the header.

Comment: @din when adding the textfield to a cell its different than in the header, for the header you must specify the height or it will be 0 (and your field won't show)

Answer (score 0):

just add this
`sectionTitleTF1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;`
then you will see it