# Insert a UITextField on top of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make UITableView, populated by user inputed data, i'm trying to display a UITextView, inside the Table View ( On Top of It ), when the users hits a button. This is what i have:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(adicionarObjeto:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

-(void)adicionarObjeto:(id)sender {

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 40)];
    [self.tableView insertSubview:myTextField atIndex:0 ];




}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having? And why are you adding the text field (not text view) at index 0? It won't be visible.

Comment: Nothing happens when i press the button. Tried to change to a UITextView, still getting the same problem.

Comment: Like I said, don't insert the text field at index 0. Use `addSubview` instead so it will be visible. And try a little larger `y` value for the frame. As-is it may be under the navigation bar (as well as behind the cells).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add UItextField into UITableview header.The following link will help you.

[add textfield to tableviewheader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034630/add-textfield-to-tableviewheader)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[self.tableView insertSubview:myTextField atIndex:[self.tableView.subviews count]];
```

Comment: Or even easier is to call `addSubview:` instead of `insertSubview:atIndex:`.